# Symfony does automatic unit tests?

Tags: php, symfony1

I noticed that symfony automatically creates functional tests for all module actions, but i'm curious if it creates unit tests too. Maybe through a plugin or something.

Comment: Automatically creates unit tests? For what?

Comment: For the models, forms, validators and modules it generates.

Answer (score 1):

The functional tests you mean are stubs - they do a very basic test, nothing else. There is no way to get unit or functional tests autogenerated for you - how would symfony know what's the expected behaviour of your appication?

Comment: It could at least create a test that instantiates one object from every model it has, just to be sure they work.